# Using reflection to get methods with certain attribute value

Tags: c#, linq

I have this delegate:

```
 public delegate void PacketHandler(Client client, Packet packet);
```

I have this attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class PacketHandlerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ServerType Server { get; private set; }
    public int Code { get; private set; }

    public PacketHandlerAttribute(ServerType server, int code)
    {
        this.Server = server;
        this.Code = code;
    }
}
```

I wanted to make a method to return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<PacketHandlerAttribute, PacketHandler>>` based on the given `ServerType` value. So, if I call this method with `ServerType.Server`, it will return all methods containing `Server1` as their attribute.

I made this so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<Doublet<PacketHandlerAttribute, PacketHandler>> GetPacketHandlers(ServerType server)
    {
        foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods())
            {
                PacketHandlerAttribute attribute = (PacketHandlerAttribute)method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(PacketHandlerAttribute));

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    if (attribute.Server == server)
                    {
                        yield return new Doublet<PacketHandlerAttribute, PacketHandler>(attribute, (PacketHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PacketHandler), method));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to ask if that's the correct way of doing this, and how can this be shortened with LINQ?

Comment: Where are you using the `server` argument?  It's not clear what you want.

Comment: @Kyle I'm not, because I don't know how to check for it. I know how to check if a method contains the attribute, but I'm not sure how to check for the `server` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that I think will help.

```
 var methods = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                      from method in type.GetMethods()
                      let attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PacketHandlerAttribute), false).Cast<PacketHandlerAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()
                      where attribute?.Code == 1
                      select new { method, attribute };
```

Your method

```
public IEnumerable<(PacketHandlerAttribute attribute, PacketHandler handler)> GetPacketHandlers(ServerType server)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

            return from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                          from method in type.GetMethods()
                          let attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PacketHandlerAttribute), false).Cast<PacketHandlerAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()
                          where attribute?.Server == server
                          select (attribute, (PacketHandler)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(PacketHandler)));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! i really do need to  laern how to use linq.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams Glad I could help. Also rewrote your method and added some c# 7 to your method for tuples.